# Create Java Plugin

Tags: java, osgi, pf4j

I have two java packages - package-A, package-B
Let us say this is the dependency chains of the packages.

```
package-A -> package-B
```

I want to pass custom Java function that would be executed in package-A. How do I do that?

```
package-A 
   - src
       - Foo.java

package-B
   - src
       - Bar.java
       - Tag.java
```

```
class Foo implements Tag {
  doThis() {
       // do what I say.
  }
}

------------------------------------------
class Bar {
    execute() {
        tag.doThis();
    }
}

interface Tag {
  doThis();
}
```

I want some sort of plugin framework, so that package-A owners can provide an implementation to all users of library package-B without package-B  having to depend on package-A

Answer (score 1):

OSGi has a *service registry*. A *plugin* (a bundle) can register a *service* object under its interface name. Other plugins can get that service. For example, in `Tag.java` we have:

```java
  public interface Tag { void doThis(); }
```

The *provider* of the service can provide an *implementation* as follows:

```java
@Component
public class Foo implements Tag {
  @Override
  public void doThis() { System.out.println("do what I say"); }
}
```

The `@Component` annotation is defined by OSGi. When the program starts, it will register a `Tag` service.

The next part is the *consumer* in `Bar.java`:

```java
@Component
public class Bar {
    @Activate public Bar( @Reference Tag tag) { tag.doThis(); }
}
```

The `@Component` will create an instance of `Bar` and will pass an instance of the `Tag` service to the constructor because it has a `@Activate` and `@Reference` annotation.

As a tip, you want to package the consumer, the interface, and the provider in three different bundles.

A simple example of this pattern is shown in a [bndtools video](https://bndtools.org/workspace.html#api--provider-project)